# API Gateway JWT Authorizer is always returning 401 even though authorization test succeeds

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jwt, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have an API Gateway that i'm trying to add JWT authorization to. I have setup the authorization lambda based on [this AWS resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html). I have tested the lambda direct and also through the 'test' button and both generate the proper response policy document just fine.

But when i test through the endpoint with postman i always get 401

```
{
    "message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

I turned on CloudWatch logging and also turned on X-Ray Tracing and the request is never logged at all. I see the logs for the test invocations and i see other logs for other non-authorized resources in CloudWatch and X-Ray.

If i disable the authorizer and deploy the request goes through just fine.

What gives?

Here is my authorizer code.

```
export async function handler(event) {
    console.log(event);
    
    let response = generatePolicy(null, 'Deny', event.methodArn);
    let token = event.authorizationToken;
    
    if (token) {
        const jwt = await validateJwtSignature(token.substring(7)); // Strip "Bearer " from the begning of the token..
        if (jwt) {
            response = generatePolicy(jwt, 'Allow', event.methodArn);
        }
    }
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    return response;
};

// Help function to generate an IAM policy
// Ex.  generatePolicy('user', 'Deny', event.methodArn);
// Ex.  generatePolicy('user', 'Allow', event.methodArn);
function generatePolicy(jwt, effect, resource) {
    const authResponse = {
        principalId: (jwt || {}).sub
    };

    if (effect && resource) {
        authResponse.policyDocument = {
            Version: '2012-10-17',
            Statement: [
                {
                    Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
                    Effect: effect,
                    Resource: resource
                }
            ]
        };
    }

    return authResponse;
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the AWS guide that is was using is not clear on step # 16 here where it says to use `authorizationToken` as the `Token source`.

This is wrong. It should be `Authorization` as that is the right header. The guide made me think that the `Token Source` and the property passed to the lambda were the same thing.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html

This is a working authorizer. Rather annoying that neither CloudWatch nor x-ray logging indicated that the request was rejected for that reason.

[image]